# Kotlin - Download a file

Tags: android, download, kotlin

I [Google searched](https://encrypted.google.com/?#q=Kotlin+download+a+file&hl=en) and discovered [Fuel](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel).
The way I attempted using this library is directly attempted from Fuel's example (downloading a file and handling the progress):

```
Fuel.Companion.download(url).destination { response, Url ->
    Log.e("Response", response.toString())
    File.createTempFile("temp", ".tmp")
}.progress { readBytes, totalBytes ->
    val progress = readBytes.toFloat() / totalBytes.toFloat()
    Log.w("Progress", progress.toString())
}.response { request, response, result ->
    Log.w("Request", request.toString())
    Log.w("Response", response.toString())
    Log.w("Result", result.toString())
}
```

Eveything's good, so far - except, where do I define the filename and the folder destination?
And also, I tested the code on an emulator, and there isn't an indication of a `temp.tmp` file.

Answer (score 0):

[File.CreateTempFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)) method has the 'directory' parameter where you can define the folder destination. Otherwise, the default temporary file directory is to be used.

Also, make sure that you've added WRITE_TO_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your build.gradle(module: app) file. If your targetSdkVersion is 23 or higher, you should implement runtime permission in your app: [Request the permissions you need](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#make-the-request)

Comment: Adding this permission, alongside the INTERNET permission, is one of the first things I did after creating this project. About the runtime permission - I'm not gonna implement the permission as "runtime permission" because it's necessary for the app to work. If the permission would be more of an optional one - I'd use a runtime permission.

Comment: What targetSdkVersion do you use?

Comment: If you don't want to use runtime permissions, max value of targetSdkVersion you can use is 22.

Comment: Oh, really? Wow.  I'll use runtime permissions then

Comment: Well, I think I nailed the runtime permissions (tested on Android O only so far, but will come back to that later). What to do now to solve the download problem?

Comment: Sorry, I've been away for a while. Did you solve your problem?